# Markdown for Drupal reference

Tags: feature-request

It would be very helpful to have specific Markdown for creating links directly to the Drupal Reference http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal, especially when you are asking/answering a question that mentions several hooks, or different modules.

I think this could be done as a sitewide thing, where a tag could be used in the bracket syntax.

- [proj:views] => [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
- [drupal6:hook_menu] => [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6)
- [drupal7:hook_boot] => [hook_boot()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7)
- [php:strpos] => [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [actionscript-3:MovieClip] => [MovieClip()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)

Most of the languages I can think of have pretty regular URLs for their online API manuals.

Comment: related discussion: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/366/automatically-link-function-names-to-api-drupal-org

Answer (score 3):

While I would like to see this feature implemented, I think it's difficult that the code running all SE sites is branched to implement a feature that is useful in just a site, or two if we include Stack Overflow.

Comment: What would be the most useful format for someone to write this as a generic JavaScript hook? Because this seems like the kind of patch any of us could write and submit for the Stack Exchange guys to look at including, right?

Comment: Stack Exchange is actually using jQuery 1.7.1. Stack Exchange is not using public available code, which means you would not be able to create a patch. If you are able to write a JavaScript library for that purpose, you can show it to the Stack Exchange staff; considering that you could create an extension for your own browser, probably they would not be interested in something that requires them to change the code they deploy for their server.