# Create a custom search filter for modules

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is a [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1236290) about drupal.org soon promoting drupal answers and the number of questions could explode.

I think it would be really useful if we could filter questions by modules referenced in the question. For example, I might want see all questions related to the flag module. 
I could envision a "Questions & Answers" link on the d.o. flag module page that will then show all related questions on d.o.

Rather than using more tags (don't think we want 10,000+ tags added), how about creating a search based on the links in the question? Most questions already have links to module pages.

The same might apply to the API pages ...

Comment: looks like you can already search for urls using url:"http://drupal.org/project/rate" or url:"*project/rate"

Comment: The likelihood of Drupal.org linking to us is slim to none: most of the people who are able to make the decision are staunchly against it, with Dries not weighing in at all after a number of months. Note the date it was first posted (August 1st, 2011) and when most of the discussion took place (August).

Comment: yeah, but quite a few people are in favor. Why don't you post there too. I wonder if someone official from SE, maybe Joel himself can get involved to get to an agrement. Seems like it's coming down to the question of "how much is SE willing to pay to the Drupal Association" ...

Comment: I spent a lot of time in August attempting to make the argument (search for Mark Trapp on the page), but gave up in frustration. The argument that keeps being brought out again and again—that we're not helping the community and that a commercial entity owns all the data—is disingenuous at best, and that we need to pay a ransom to get listed is just ridiculous.

Comment: damn politics, I hear ya ;-) Maybe I feel the same in 4 months from now if nothing happens ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It could work if there is a URL in the question that points to a project page; in this case, it is already possible [to search for questions containing a link to a project page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:question%20url:%22http://drupal.org/project/*%22&submit=search). If the question doesn't contain a link, you can always look for the questions containing the reference to a module, but you would need to look for a very specific phrase, to avoid false positives caused by the name used for Drupal modules (e.g. Rate, Views). You could look for phrases like "the Rate module," but very few questions refer to a module in that way.

This feature request is related to the one asking to expand the Markdown syntax to allow automatic links to project pages, done on [Markdown for Drupal reference](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/markdown-for-drupal-api-reference). Suppose that [module:views] would be rendered, through a JavaScript library, as a link to the project page for the Views module; in that case, it would be easy to find the reference to the Views module. Still there will be the problem of questions that don't use that markup when referring to modules.

Comment: that approach would be nice but probably tough to implement. Most questions and answers already contain the link to d.o. Maybe we'll just make it best practice to always include those links. Then anyone can use the url search to link to questions related to a specific module. I think module maintainers might like the idea of having support questions "offloaded" to this site rather than the issue queue ;-)

Comment: The issue queue for a project is not generally a good place for asking for support, especially if you are asking for something too localized. The problem is that issue queues don't have a high visibility, compared to forums. If you are asking something that just the maintainer can know, then the issue queue is the place to ask; if you are asking something to which also somebody else is able to answer, then forums or DA is better.