# Typing shortcut for project links?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown for Drupal reference](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/markdown-for-drupal-reference)

Do we have (and if not - could we have) a typing shortcut to insert links to projects (modules, themes)? Just as we have syntax for `[tag:elephants]`, I would like to be able to write `[proj:project_name]` to easily insert links to `http://drupal.org/project/project_name` when giving an answer or comment.

Comment: I merged your request with the existing one, as the answer to both the feature requests is the same; if Stack Exchange is going to implement this, it is also going to implement the other feature request.